# Pass variable back through class

Tags: flutter

i've a problem about passing variable back to the "super" class which is calling my "sub" class.

I have a custom class in the body:

```
body: AppWithNotification(
        notification: Notifiche(),
        notificationHeight: this.altezza,
        backgroundOpacity: this.opacita,
      )
```

Then I have the "bottomNavigationBar" of the app.
But for making my app more clean, i moved the code in another class (in another file, so my call is:

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BarraSotto();
```

In BarraSotto I have a button.
So my question is: how can I call a setState for change this.altezza and this.opacita in the Homepage class from the button that is in the BarraSotto class?

If i write all inline maybe it's ok, i want that all my page will contains the same bottomNavigationBar, so i need a class in another file that i can re-use...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution.

You have to create a callback function in the motherclass that will do your setState.

Then, in the subclass you will create a constructor with function param, and you will pass there the callback.

This in BarraSotto class:

```
final Function showNotifiche;

BarraSotto(this.showNotifiche);
```

Here the callback in the home:

```
showNotifiche()
{
  setState(() {
   this.altezza = 300;
   this.opacita = .5;
  });
}
```

And here how to pass it:

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BarraSotto(() => showNotifiche())
```